# Gensim: calling docvecs.most_similar yields error

Tags: python, numpy, gensim

When I call `docvecs.most_similar` on a document, I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`:

```
# load model from file
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
model_doc2vec = Doc2Vec.load("/path_to_file/doc2vec.bin")

# attempt to get most similar documents from docvec
tokens = "in space".split()
new_vector = model_doc2vec.infer_vector(tokens)
sims = model_doc2vec.docvecs.most_similar( positive=[new_vector], topn=10 )
```

which yields `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`.

I have a hunch this may have to do with numpy and gensim version compatibility.  I am using Python 3.6, numpy 1.14, and gensim 1.0.1.

Full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-220db2331e84> in <module>()
----> 1 sims = model_doc2vec.docvecs.most_similar( positive=[new_vector], topn=10 )

~/doc2vec.py in most_similar(self, positive, negative, topn, clip_start, clip_end, indexer)
    436         there was chosen to be significant, such as more popular tag IDs in lower indexes.)
    437         """
--> 438         self.init_sims()
    439         clip_end = clip_end or len(self.doctag_syn0norm)
    440 

~/doc2vec.py in init_sims(self, replace)
    419                         mode='w+', shape=self.doctag_syn0.shape)
    420                 else:
--> 421                     self.doctag_syn0norm = empty(self.doctag_syn0.shape, dtype=REAL)
    422                 np_divide(self.doctag_syn0, sqrt((self.doctag_syn0 ** 2).sum(-1))[..., newaxis], self.doctag_syn0norm)
    423 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: The error message seems to be more like the code expects a numpy array which has the attribute `shape`  but is getting a list. Why are you using such an old version of gensim? It's at 3.5.0 now.

Comment: I've tried multiple versions of gensim, both older and newer that give me the same message, including gensim 3.5.  I haven't tried Python 2.7 yet, though.

Comment: FWIW, I tried Python 2.7, but it's most likely that the training data was deleted (and is not / cannot be reconstructed by the model).  Infer still works for me, which is the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RTFD](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html):

> delete_temporary_training_data(keep_doctags_vectors=True,
>   keep_inference=True) 
>   Discard parameters that are used in training and
>   score. Use if you’re sure you’re done training a model.
>
> Parameters:    keep_doctags_vectors (bool, optional) – Set to False if
>   you don’t want to save doctags vectors. **In this case you will not be
>   able to use most_similar()**, similarity(), etc methods. keep_inference
>   (bool, optional) – Set to False if you don’t want to store parameters
>   that are used for infer_vector() method.